# Delete Term from Custom Taxonomy using wp_delete_term isn't working

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created custom taxonomy called **program** using Custom Post Type Plugin. I want to create functions using add_action that can create and delete term which has the same name as the post automatically whenever the post is published or trashed.

Here are the code:

```
add_action( 'publish_program-peduli', 'add_program_term' );
add_action('deleted_program-peduli', 'delete_program_term_automatically');

function delete_program_term_automatically($post_ID) {
    $cat = get_post($post_ID);
    $termslug = $cat->post_name;
    $queryTerm = new WP_Term_Query( array('taxonomy' => 'program', 'slug' => $termslug, 'hide_empty' => false ));
    $termID = $queryTerm->get_terms()[0]->term_id;
    do_action( 'qm/debug', wp_delete_term($termID, 'program'));
}

function add_program_term( $post_ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_ID ); // get post object
    wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'program' );
    do_action( 'qm/debug', $post->post_title);
}
```

the create term function is working, but not for the remove term. It always return false. Please help

Comment: `false` means that the term doesn't exist. Have you verified that `$termID` is what you expect it to be? What about the other variables?

Comment: the $termID output is correct. It returns term_id as int. What makes me confuse is when i'm using wp_delete_term on category or tags is worked

Comment: I tried ```wp_delete_term(50, 'program'), ```. where 50 is the term_id for specific term in my custom taxonomy. it also fails

Comment: "*It always return false*" - how did you confirm it returns `false`? What code you use to check for that value? (Presumably, it's the callback hooked on `qm/debug`) And just to be sure, are you completely certain that `delete_program_term_automatically` is being executed? Are you also certain that `program` is the correct taxonomy? Have you tried with other registered *custom* taxonomies - did it work?

Comment: I asked if it's being executed, because I'm not aware of a `deleted_<post type>` hook?  Only [`deleted_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/#hooks).

Comment: I changed the taxonomy with the category like this ```do_action( 'qm/debug', wp_delete_term($termID, 'category'));``` where the $termID is the same as term_id from category. But it returns true.

Comment: Let's says that I'm using the right taxonomy. I think the term_id is not the problem because i have verified by myself`using ```get_terms()```. Maybe you can suggest the right code?

Comment: okay. But i tried both deleted_post and trashed_post. No difference

Comment: Were you actually referring to the return value of `do_action()` and not `wp_delete_term()`? Try replacing the `do_action()` line with `error_log( var_export( [ __FUNCTION__, $termID, taxonomy_exists( 'program' ), get_term_field( 'slug', $termID, 'program' ), $cat->post_name, wp_delete_term($termID, 'program') ], true ) );` and see the error log to check the debug output, and then *add it to your post* so that everyone here can clearly see it. Btw, please tag my username when replying, @MuhammadAlFatih.

Comment: Basically though, I don't think you're using the proper hook to run your action/code, and the code itself has several issues. But let's first see what the `var_export()` outputs. And do try with both the `deleted_program-peduli` and `deleted_post` actions, and be sure to add a `if ( ! $cat || 'program-peduli' !== $cat->post_type ) { return; }` **after** the `$cat = get_post($post_ID);` line, and add the debug output for each of that actions.

Comment: The log method you made is big help to me. Finally, I know the problem was slug of the the post that become `[slug]_trashed`. So i just need to remove `_trashed` to match the category slug. Thank you @SallyCJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution for the code. Thank you my friend [@SallyCJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) for helping me out.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'publish_program-peduli', 'add_program_term' );
add_action( 'deleted_post', 'delete_program_term');

function add_program_term( $post_ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_ID ); // get post object
    wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'program' );
}

function delete_program_term($post_ID) {
    $cat = get_post($post_ID);
    if ( ! $cat || 'program-peduli' !== $cat->post_type ) { return; }
    $termslug = $cat->post_name;
    $queryTerm = get_term_by( 'slug', substr($termslug, 0, -9) , 'program');
    $termID = $queryTerm->term_id;
    wp_delete_term($termID, 'program');
}
```